# Is there any algorithm to find the nth term in a series where we add previous three elements to get the nth element with less than O(n) complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

The series goes like:
1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24.... and so on
To get the 4th term we add 1, 2 and 4: 1+2+4 = 4

It could be solved using a for loop with O(n) complexity, here is the code for that

```
static int fib(int n) 
    { 
        int a = 1, b = 2, c = 4, d; 
        if (n == 1) 
            return a;
        if (n == 2) 
            return b;
        if (n == 3) 
            return c;
        for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++) 
        { 
            d = a + b + c; 
            a = b; 
            b = c; 
            c = d; 
        } 
        return d; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes: Pre-calculate a table of values. Then use `n` as an index into the table, with O(1) complexity.

Comment: Your series is created by a rule very similar to the Fibonacci series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Therefore I would research in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Can be solved using Matrix exponential algorithm. Matrix Exponential algorithm works with O(logn) complexity .

Links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/
https://www.hackerearth.com/ja/practice/notes/matrix-exponentiation-1/
https://riptutorial.com/algorithm/example/24256/matrix-exponentiation-to-solve-example-problems
http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/11/matrix-exponentiation.html

Here first link describes your problem. And also added others link of matrix exponential for details.